# Is it possible for "alwaysIn" (state functions) select from set of values?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, solver, constraint-programming, docplex

State functions looks like the best option for modeling my situation.

[The image as it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nEuX.png)

Now interval variable X might be in range of state functin  **from** 'vmin' **to** 'vmax'.

But in my situation any interval variable is related to **set of states** and this states are not going in order.

For example, interval "product_1_Interval" is related to states 1 and 3. And not allowed in state 2.
But interval "product_2_Interval" is related to states 2 and 3.

My desirable situation is this one:
[the image about how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF0SQ.png)

OPL Code example:

```
stateFunction myStateFunction;
dvar interval product_1_Interval;
dvar interval product_2_Interval;

subject to
{
alwaysConstant (myStateFunction, 0, 155);
alwaysConstant (myStateFunction, 156, 310);

/* Below need constraint that interval variable product_1_Interval might be in state 1 or 3 */
/* Below need constraint that interval variable product_2_Interval might be in state 2 or 3 */

}
```

I've tried to write something like:

```
alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  1) or alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  3);
```

But I got an error "Exception in presolve: Constraint 'alwaysEqual' is a top level constraint, it cannot be used in an expression..".

My question: Is it possible now in CPLEX Solver to model situation when an interval variable relates to some set of states (stateFunction) which are not going in order?

Answer (score 0):

I would use alternative and write

```
using CP;

{int} options={1,3};

stateFunction myStateFunction;
dvar interval product_1_Interval;
dvar interval product_1_Interval_v[options] optional in 0..100 size 100 ;

dvar interval product_2_Interval in 0..10;


subject to
{
alwaysConstant (myStateFunction, 0, 155);
alwaysConstant (myStateFunction, 156, 310);

alternative(product_1_Interval,all(v in options)product_1_Interval_v[v]);

/* Below need constraint that interval variable product_1_Interval might be in state 1 or 3 */
/* Below need constraint that interval variable product_2_Interval might be in state 2 or 3 */


//alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  1) or alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  3);

forall(v in options)alwaysEqual(myStateFunction,product_1_Interval_v[v],  v);


}

execute
{
  writeln(myStateFunction);
}
```

and to get something like you look for

```
using CP;

{int} options={1,3};

stateFunction myStateFunction;
dvar interval product_1_Interval size 150;
dvar interval product_1_Interval_v[options]  optional;

dvar interval product_2_Interval size 150;
dvar interval product_2_Interval_v[options]  optional;

subject to
{
alwaysConstant (myStateFunction, 0, 155);
alwaysConstant (myStateFunction, 156, 310);

endAtStart(product_1_Interval,product_2_Interval,1);

alternative(product_1_Interval,all(v in options)product_1_Interval_v[v]);
alternative(product_2_Interval,all(v in options)product_2_Interval_v[v]);

/* Below need constraint that interval variable product_1_Interval might be in state 1 or 3 */
/* Below need constraint that interval variable product_2_Interval might be in state 2 or 3 */


//alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  1) or alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  3);

forall(v in options)alwaysEqual(myStateFunction,product_1_Interval_v[v],  v);
forall(v in options)alwaysEqual(myStateFunction,product_2_Interval_v[v],  v);

presenceOf(product_2_Interval_v[1])!=presenceOf(product_1_Interval_v[1]);

}

execute
{
  writeln(myStateFunction);
}
```

gives

```
stepwise{ -1 -> 0; 1 -> 155; 3 -> 310; -1 }
```

[image]

and

```
using CP;

{int} options={1,3};

stateFunction myStateFunction;
dvar interval product_1_Interval size 10..200;
dvar interval product_1_Interval_v[options]  optional;

dvar interval product_2_Interval size 10..200;
dvar interval product_2_Interval_v[options]  optional;

subject to
{
alwaysConstant (myStateFunction, 0, 155);
alwaysConstant (myStateFunction, 156, 310);

endAtStart(product_1_Interval,product_2_Interval,1);

alternative(product_1_Interval,all(v in options)product_1_Interval_v[v]);
alternative(product_2_Interval,all(v in options)product_2_Interval_v[v]);

/* Below need constraint that interval variable product_1_Interval might be in state 1 or 3 */
/* Below need constraint that interval variable product_2_Interval might be in state 2 or 3 */


//alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  1) or alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  3);

forall(v in options)alwaysEqual(myStateFunction,product_1_Interval_v[v],  v);
forall(v in options)alwaysEqual(myStateFunction,product_2_Interval_v[v],  v);

presenceOf(product_2_Interval_v[1])!=presenceOf(product_1_Interval_v[1]);

startOf(product_1_Interval) == 120;

}

execute
{
  writeln(myStateFunction);
  writeln(product_1_Interval);
  writeln(product_2_Interval);
}
```

gives

```
stepwise{ -1 -> 0; 1 -> 155; 3 -> 310; -1 }
 <1 120 154 34>
 <1 155 165 10>
```

Comment: thank you very much for fast answer. But it is not exactly I need. Please, look at my desirable image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF0SQ.png). In fact alwaysEqual won't help me, because an interval might be between states. And so I used alwaysIn(...). But alwaysIn might be in a range, e.g. from 1 to 3. But I need only 1 and 3, not 2.

Comment: With the alternative? I was able to write "alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  1) or alwaysEqual(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval,  3);"

Comment: I'm sorry for my inaccuracy. I mean "Below need constraint that interval variable product_1_Interval might be in state 1 or 3 **AT THE SAME TIME**".
So left part of interval 'product_1_Interval' is in state 1, but right part of 'interval product_1_Interval' is in state 3 **at the same time**.
Like on the picture: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF0SQ.png)

Comment: Because of it I've started my post with talking about "alwaysIn". As I see it is possible that one interval covers several states from min to max. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nEuX.png)
In my task I need describe a constraint that one interval covers several states from set of int values.
So I'm looking for a code like: `alwaysIn(myStateFunction, product_1_Interval, options)`
Is it possible?

Comment: I add to your code follow constrait: `startOf(product_1_Interval) == 120;` and solver returns 'Conflict found' and no solusion. But it is exactly I need. That states are constant from 0 to 155 and from 156 to 300. But position of interval "product_1_Interval" is somwhere on the border of states. Again, sorry for my inaccuracy.

Comment: I asked the same  question in another way here https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/is-it-possible-for-alwaysin-state-functions-select-from-set-of-values#bmd4da75ad-5732-43ab-9f8a-5cae752034a2